# How to fix erro for a list that might contain negative numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get cagr for list ab:

```
ab=[10,20,356,-67]

abyear= sum(map(lambda x : x !=0, ab))
```

My fomula used to get **cagr**

```
ab_cagr=(((ab[0]/ab[abyear-1])**(1/abyear))-1)
```

it gave me an **error** :

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

Then i tried :

```
def abcagr():
    if ab[abyear-1] > 0 and ab[0] >=0 : return (((ab[0]/ab[abyear-1])**(1/abyear))-1)
    else: return 0


abc_cagr=abcagr()*100
```

and also get the same error .

The list of ab is example and it might be that the whole list might be negative or only 1 might nbe negative. How to fix such issue?

Comment: Your first formula doesn't produce any error. Please provide a minimal piece of relevant code that we can directly copy and run and that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I would assume - try upgrading your python version. I suspect the error is because of the `map` - but that's just a guess, since it doesn't produce any error for me

Comment: `ab[0]/ab[abyear-1]**(1/abyear)` is returning a complex number because `ab[abyear-1]**(1/abyear)` = -67 ^ (1/4), which is an imaginary number, since you're taking an even root of a negative number (which has no real solutions). Is this the intended behaviour or is it a mistake? What is ab_cagr meant to do? Would help if you specified what your goal is.

Comment: so data are retrived from DB based on input. For some request this list might contain negative numbers others not. When i get this specific request for example name of student Alex he can have negative grade in list of subjects so calculting cagr would give such error

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski  python 3.8

Comment: @ WeavingBird1917 my goal just make the cagr formula applicable to all types of lists even if the list would contain negative number. I assume this is because of negative number rooted. I agree with you

Comment: The code above does not throw an error, but we don't know what `proficagr()` is; that might be throwing the error. Perhaps it would be clearer if you put down a pseudocode of what you're trying to do, or the mathematical steps.

Comment: You can't use such a formula for values that can have various signs or be zero. There is no rate that could possibly make you go from a negative value to a positive one in 2 years, for example (unless you accept complex rates...). Also, if grades can be negative, can they also be zero? How would a rate applied on 0 give anything else than 0?

Comment: i just need to get cagr whenever number is so it might be that the list migt contain negtive ones so what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the value of `ab`, `(ab[0]/ab[abyear-1])` might evaluate to a negative number and `(1/abyear)` might be smaller than 1, in which case `ab_cagr` will be a complex number. This is what happened in your example.

Comparing a complex number with a real number / float makes no mathematical sense. Do you mean to compare the modulus of the complex number with the float instead?

I don't know what the code is intended for but in any case, you need to sanitize the input and handle these cases appropriately.